# Is it possible write query for EventLogQuery using 'Like'

Tags: c#, xpath, query-string, windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer

I need to filter and say for example PackageFullName should start with '6', how filter using some pattern?

```
 string query = "*[System/EventID=400 ] and *[System/Opcode=2] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='PackageFullName'] LIKE '6%']]";
```

Comment: The Event Log service only supports a subset of XPath functions, neither of which will allow you to do wildcard string matching. Pipe the resulting events to `Where-Object` to filter them

Comment: I researched that can be used 'contains', but it also not work for me, getting exception which says 'The specified query is invalid'

Comment: `contains()` is part of the XPath specification, yes, but it is _not_ supported by the Event Log service in Windows. `position()`/`timediff()`/`band()` are the **only** XPath functions supported when constructing event log queries, using any other function will result in "The specified query is invalid"

Comment: so for this *[EventData[Data[@Name='PackageFullName'] how can I check is the value contain or start with '6' , can you provide me complete query ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen or it means that it is not possible  ?

Comment: No, it's not possible _with XPath alone_, I've posted an answer below to show how you could do it in your own code though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the Event Log service on Windows does **not** support the full XPath grammar - and it certainly doesn't support substring-matching functions like `contains()`/`starts-with()`/`ends-with()`.

Instead, you'll need to fetch all the events and then filter them by inspecting the data value in your own code.

To extract the individual `<Data />` nodes' values from the event data section, use the [`GetPropertyValues()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.getpropertyvalues) with an appropriate `EventLogPropertySelector` to grab the string value, then manually inspect it:

```
string logName = "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-Gateway";
string queryText = "*[System/EventID=400 ] and *[System/Opcode=2] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='PackageFullName']]]";

// This is the query definition the reader will use to pre-filter event records
var query = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, queryText);
// This is a property selector that we'll be using to extract the event data afterwards
var packageNameSelector = new EventLogPropertySelector(new []{ "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='PackageFullName']" });

using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query))
{
    // Keep reading...
    EventLogRecord record;
    while((record = reader.ReadEvent() as EventLogRecord) is not null)
    {
        // Fetch the package name and inspect before moving ahead
        var propertyValues = record.GetPropertyValues(packageNameSelector);
        if(propertyValues.Count > 0 && propertyValues[0] is string pkgName && pkgName.StartsWith("6"))
        {
            // matching event, do what you need here 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do it in a query and this is the second thing that I thought, anyway thank you for your support it is really useful.